# Detect deletion of instance variable or its element (list of objects)?

Tags: python, oop, overriding

I came across this OOP exercise in Python which states following:

```
Class Battery:
    def __init__(self, member1: int, member2: int, lead: str):
         self.member1 = member1
         self.member2 = member2
         self.lead = lead

Class Robot:
    def __init__(self, robot_name: str, leads: tuple[str, ...], batteries: list[Battery], num_batteries: int):
         self.robot_name = robot_name
         self.leads = leads
         self.batteries = batteries
         self.num_batteries = num_batteries
```

Now I'm supposed to detect the following deletion:

```
del robot1.batteries[2]
```

And correspondingly update other instance variables (num_batteries and leads - decrease the number of batteries and remove the lead at the same index position as the battery).

**What I tried so far:**

1. I already tried overriding below magic method, but without any success.

   ```
   __delitem__(self, key)
   ```
2. I was thinking about implementing a deleter method, which would result into defining those members as properties (which is completely fine, just not sure if the exercise is meant to be done like that)

   ```
   @name.deleter
   ```

This brought me to a thinking, that maybe in order to be able to do this I need to have custom list and not the python default one. After all, I'm tampering with the list content and trying to replicate it on other logical parts. Have you got any ideas how could such a thing be implemented?

Comment: `num_batteries` is always just `len(self.batteries)`, no? Make `num_batteries` a *property* which simply `return len(self.batteries)`, instead of an independent attribute…?

Comment: Is `num_batteries` how many batteries fit in the robot, and not the current count?

Comment: @deceze actually a good idea, now only leads need to be handled..

Comment: @James it is actually the current count. In practice it doesn't make sense to have a separate member for that, but I guess this was for the exercise purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Are you sure it must work with `del robot1.batteries[2]`?
You could theoretically override `__delitem__` but it is a method of `list`, so you would need to define your own class that inherits from `list` to use for `Robot.batteries` and you would have to create a reference back to the robot.

This technically works but it is really ugly and I highly doubt that it was the intention of the exercise. If it is about OOP, you should probably rather write some methods for `Robot` like `remove_battery` that handle everything instead on relying on `del`.

```py
class Battery:
    def __init__(self, member1: int, member2: int):
        self.member1 = member1
        self.member2 = member2


class BatteryList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.robot = None

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        battery = self.__getitem__(key)
        print(f"deleting {battery} ({key})")
        if self.robot is not None:
            self.robot.leads[battery.member1] = None
            self.robot.leads[battery.member2] = None

    def register(self, robot: "Robot"):
        self.robot = robot


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, robot_name: str, leads: list[str, ...], batteries: BatteryList[Battery], num_batteries: int):
        self.robot_name = robot_name
        self.leads = leads
        self.batteries = batteries
        self.num_batteries = num_batteries

        self.batteries.register(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    robot1 = Robot(
        robot_name="foo",
        leads=["lead0", "lead1", "lead2", "lead3", "lead4", "lead5"],
        batteries=BatteryList([Battery(0, 1), Battery(2, 3), Battery(4, 5)]),
        num_batteries=3,
    )
    print(f"start: {robot1.leads}")
    del robot1.batteries[2]
    print(f"end: {robot1.leads}")
```

Comment: No no no - `Battery.__del__` will only be called if the target of `del` was the last remaining reference to the Battery - and it will receive no information at all as to which Robot was using that Battery.

Comment: @jasonharper correct. I also tried overriding __del__ method, but completely forgot about it. The thing is, it never invoked, but I wasn't sure why. I didn't really focus on it, because I wasn't sure how to reference to the specific "robot" containing the battery.

Comment: @Baumkuchen seems like a workaround, the only problem is I am bound to the two classes (Battery and Robot). Yes, it was supposed to be a pretty easy OOP exercise, but they supplied unit tests and the particular unit test is fed with hardcoded batteries, leads and num_batteries. The del is called on batteries list and then the leads content and num_batteries is being compared. Weird...